# pentaho cde dashboard charts with clickview and dragview functionality

Tags: pentaho, dashboard-designer

I am new to Penatho BI, I am using pentaho CDE tool to create Dashboard reports.
How to create dashboard bar chart with click view or drag view functionality. i.e whenever we do mouse drag on any one bar in the bar chart, it will show the detailed view report or data.

Please help me on this.

Thanks in advance,
Suresh

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever worked with CDE dashboard? Ctools supports good javascript dashboard